# How to use the variable globally in the function

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, structure

I am writing a C code to insert an element to a sorted linked list. In this code I am using the variable "place" for deciding the position to insert the new element. But here it is getting error that "place" variable is to declared first. But I need the place globally for using in other functions. So what can I do to make it work? Also there is some problem with the function calling in the last part of main function. Please help me to correct it. Please let me know if there are any other errors. Thank You

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
int calcSize(struct Node* node){
    int size=0;
    while(node!=NULL){
        node = node->next;
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}

void insertPosition(int pos, int data, struct Node** head)
{
    int size = calcSize(*head);
    if(pos < 1 || size < pos) 
    { 
        printf("Can't insert, %d is not a valid position\n",pos); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        struct Node* temp = *head; 
        struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*) 
        malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        while(--pos)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        newNode->next= temp->next;
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}

void insertStart(struct Node** head, int data){

    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
}

void insertLast(struct Node** head, int data){

    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(*head==NULL){
        *head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    struct Node* temp = *head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
        temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;
}

void display(struct Node* node){

    while(node!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void check(struct Node* node,int ele){
    while(node!=NULL){
        int i=0;
        if(ele>node->data)
        { place=i; break;}
        node= node->next;
    }
}
int main()
{   int ele; int place=0;
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* node2 = NULL; 
    struct Node* node3 = NULL; 
    struct Node* node4 = NULL; 
    struct Node* node5 = NULL;
    
    head =  (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
    node2 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
    node3 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
    node4 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node5 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    
    head->data = 5; head->next = node2; 
    node2->data = 10; node2->next = node3; 
    node3->data = 18; node3->next = node4; 
    node4->data = 26; node4->next = node5;
    node5->data = 32; node5->next = NULL;
    
    printf("Current Items in Linked List\n");
    display(head); 
    printf("Enter the element to insert into LL\n");
    scanf("%d",&ele);
    printf("Inserting into Linked List....");
    if(place=1)
    { void insertStart(&head, ele); }
    else if(place=5)
    { void insertLast(&head, ele); }
    else
    { void insertPosition(place, ele, &head); }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: "Also there is some problem" That is not a very helpfuls description. What problems are there?

Comment: 1) `if(place=1)` This is not a comparison but an assignment. Your compiler should warn you.  2) `{ void insertStart(&head, ele); }` This is not how functions are called. That is a function declaration. If you want to call that function, remove the `void`.  --- Both issues appear multiple times

Comment: It is possible to declare variables at file scope.  Such variables will be accessible by name to at least all functions defined later in the same source file.  But **this is usually a bad way for functions to communicate**, and if you don't mean to use such a variable to communicate data between functions, then each function can just declare its own.

Comment: If you need `place` in a function, why not pass it as a parameter? Global variables should be avoided

Comment: There are multiple alternatives to communicating via global variables, but the simplest and most common are via function parameters and via return values.